# Is it Possible to to call a function in a case of a switch control flow?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Could I really do that?

example:

```
switch($string){
 case function_name(preferably built-in functions): 
  //codes to run...
  break;
  ....
  ....

}
```

Comment: I am not sure, it is possible, but why would you need that, you can get value in advance and then place it in case statment

Comment: Why not just try it? (Spoiler: you can, I just tried it. :))

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

You can call either built-in function or user-defined function as case expressions.

As an example:

```
function foo() { return 1; }    
function bar() { return 2; }
$var = 3;    
switch($var) {
    case foo():
        echo "FOO\n";break;
    case bar():
        echo "BAR\n";break;
    case max(1,2,3):
        echo "MAX\n"; break;
}
```

outputs

```
MAX
```

You can take a look at the Grammar of PHP [here](http://www.icosaedro.it/articoli/php-syntax-ebnf.txt) and the switch construct is defined as:

```
switch_case_list = "{" [";"] {case_list} "}"
    | ":" [";"] {case_list} "endswitch" ";" ;

case_list = "case" expr [":"|";"] inner_statement_list
    | "default" [":"|";"] inner_statement_list ;
```

Clearly the `case` can be followed by an `expr` and if you see the definition of expr you'll see that a function call fall in that.

Comment: switch($var){
 case is_numeric(this):
 //

}


could it be possible .. like in jQuery the 'this' variable works great. but i don't know about PHP .. what it would look like..